# Rails Admin: too many dropdown entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, rails-admin

in my rails_admin application, I have a table "Branch" that references another table called "Alarms". In "Branches", I'd like to select exactly one alarm and have a search box to search these alarms.

Currently, I'm only capable to create a drop down with all alarms related to that branch which causes many entries to be rendered (over 25k) and memory to be consumed.
I couldn't find an example how to create a dropdown that says "too many entries, search to select", similar to the `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Here's how it looks:

```rb
class Branch < ApplicationRecord
...
  # this is fine and works as expected, selecting only the first (and only) entry
  show do
    field :maintenance_period_trigger_alarm_id do
      formatted_value do
        alarm = Alarm.where(id: bindings[:object].maintenance_period_trigger_alarm_id).first
        path = bindings[:view].show_path(model_name: 'alarm', id: alarm.id)
        bindings[:view].link_to(alarm.name, path)
      end
    end
  end
  ...
  # this is where all elements are automatically loaded and rendered in the dropdown
  edit do
    field :maintenance_period_trigger_alarm_id, :enum do
      enum do
        Alarm.where(branch_id: bindings[:controller].params[:id]).collect{ |alarm| [alarm.name, alarm.id] }
      end
    end
  end
```

I'm not sure how I can enable a simple "Too many entries" message to not show 25k entries in there.

Comment: [`count`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count) the records and if it exceeds a certain threshold, show a static message instead of populating the dropdown.

Comment: What you are looking for is a select field that doesn't get pre-populated with select options but that will dynamically start to query the server for matching options when the user starts to enter a search string. Have a look at [https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax). Let me know if you need any help implementing it!

Comment: Following @AndreasGebhard idea you can use the built-in select options dropdown, if you want to follow that route i can flesh it out for you on an answer

Comment: i'm open to either approach. But I'm not sure how to implement it since I'm not great with rails (not to say terrible) and the code base doesn't have something I can copy and extend. A fleshed out answer sounds thrilling.

Answer (score 0):

@zokkker13, here is a very basic fleshed-out example that will query a `people_controller.rb` for people by name.

**Add select2 to your page**
Either [download](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation) select2.js and select2.css, put them into your vendor folder and add them to your applications.js and application.css files, or just
[include them from a CDN](https://github.com/select2/select2/archive/4.0.13.zip) into your page. Load your page and use your browser's dev tools to make sure that `select2.js` is loaded.

**Add a new route to `config/routes.rb`**

```
resources :people do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
```

Restart your server.

**Add search action to `people_controller.rb`**

```
# coding: utf-8
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  def search
    
    # https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax
    term = params[:term]
    matches = Person.where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{term}%").to_a
    
    # https://select2.org/data-sources/formats
    matches.map!{ |m| { id: m.id, text: m.name } }
    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {
        render status: 200, json: { results: matches }
      }
    end

  end

end
```

**Add search box to page**
Add this to your html page:

```
<%= select_tag :search, nil, id: 'select2-live-search-people' %>
<script>
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#select2-live-search-people').select2({
      ajax: { url: '/people/search', dataType: 'json' },
      placeholder: 'Start typing to search...',
      width: '300px',
      minimumInputLength: 3
    });
  } );
</script>
```

.. or this, if you use haml:

```
= select_tag :search, nil, id: 'select2-live-search-people'
:javascript
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#select2-live-search-people').select2({
      ajax: { url: '/people/search', dataType: 'json' },
      placeholder: 'Start typing to search...',
      width: '300px',
      minimumInputLength: 3
    });
  } );
```

Modify the code so that it will query an existing model w/ existing data. Then relaod the page and start typing. You should now see the select option getting adjusted to the result of your search term. Use the `minimumInputLength` parameter to control how many characters are minimally needed to issue an ajax call. With potentially 25k options, you might want to increase it even more.

Comment: @zokkker13 any luck with issue?